# Is the Akka Abstract FSM interface deprecated?

Tags: java, akka, pom.xml, fsm

I am trying to write a Finite state machine actor for my application using the AbstractFSM interface as in this doc
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/java/fsm.html

I am using version 2.5.3 of teh framework, this is the pom file

```
<!-- Akka Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-kernel_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I cant seem to import , `AbstractFSM<S,D>`, even after importing the following line

```
import akka.actor.*;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractFSM isn't deprecated and my IDE doesn't have problems finding it, so I think it's something to do with  your dependencies. I see 2 problems. Notice your akka-remote and akka-kernel are using the _2.10 artifacts, while actor and testkit are using _2.12. These versions should match. Also, your akka-remote is in version 2.5.0 while others are in 2.5.3. These should match as well.

One dependency I cannot find in those versions is akka-kernel. Also, it seems to be missing from the current documentation website, so perhaps that's been discontinued.

Comment: Thanks ! I guess that was it